# Pricing is showing £10.4 instead of £10.40

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I have this code which display how much a customer has left to spend if they are to qualify for free delivery.

```
if ($sub_total < 75)
            { ?>
            <div class="free_delivery-sub_total"><p class="free_delivery_message">
                <?php echo 'Spend another '.$to_go_delivery .' to qualify for free delivery';?> </p>
                <p class="international_message"><?php echo '*Free delivery excludes international delivery';
            ?></p></div><?php }}?>
```

however the price is being formatted wrong. it is showing £4.1 instead of £4.10 how can i get it to print the zero as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_finalPrice,true,false);
```

This should format your price.

So your code should be something like:

```
<?php echo 'Spend another '.Mage::helper('core')->currency($_finalPrice, true, false);.' to qualify for free delivery';?>
```

Comment: Yea little bit of editing but it worked thank you. will accept your answer when it lets me